# ADFS SAML request is not signed with expected signature algorithm

Tags: saml, saml-2.0, adfs, adfs3.0

ADFS has unexpected behavior that looks like a bug.

I have SP that is using SHA1 hash algorithm for digital signing.
On ADFS for this SP I set on advanced tab to use SHA256.

For me it is normal that these are not in correlation each side choose how will sign.

When I did sign out from SP I did signing with SHA1. On ADFS I got exception :

```
SAML request is not signed with expected signature algorithm. SAML request is signed with signature algorithm http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256 . Expected signature algorithm is http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1
```

I am using ADFS 3 , Windows R2

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the signing algorithm in ADFS from SHA256 to SHA1. This will solve the exception.

Comment: this helped. Looks like related to unlimited crypto policies.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm using SimpleSAMLphp as my SP, I was getting the exact same error on logout. Hopefully my solution will be able to help some people.

I added the following line to the config for my IDP in the authsources.php file, then re-imported the metadata on the IDP (not sure if that step was required):-

`'signature.algorithm' => 'http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256',`

Answer (score 0):

For those using the [Ruby SAML gem](https://github.com/onelogin/ruby-saml), if you are unable to change the signing algorithm within ADFS, you can set the `SAML` settings like this:

`settings.security[:signature_method] = XMLSecurity::Document::RSA_SHA256`

I hope that becomes useful to someone in the future!